# pnp4nagios does not generate perfdata

Tags: nagios

I am running nagios2, pnp4nagios-0.6.16 and php 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.19.

In my setup, pnp4nagios is correctly generating perfdata, which can be seen via the web interface in graphical form for lots of services.

The perfdata directory contains entries of the kind:

```
/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/zeus/Disk_Space_Home.rrd
/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/zeus/Disk_Space_Home.xml
```

I have activated performance data for a new nagios service:

```
define serviceextinfo {
    host_name                       zeus
    service_description             450average
    action_url                      /pnp4nagios/index.php?host=$HOSTNAME$&srv=$SERVICEDESC$
}
```

This service is generating monitoring data in the format:

```
status_info|perf_data
```

as required for performance gathering.

But somehow the performance data related to this service is not being collected by pnp4nagios (no related entries in `/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata`)

Are there any pnp4nagios scripts or settings which I could use to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

somewhere in your nagios configuration you need to assign the proper command to process perfdata aswell.

something like this

```
define command {
       command_name    process-service-perfdata
       command_line    /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl
}

define command {
       command_name    process-host-perfdata
       command_line    /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl -d HOSTPERFDATA
}
```

also your template/service definition must have 'process_perf_data 1'

Answer (score 0):

To get performance data collection started, you must make sure that the format of the data produced is:

```
label=value<unit>;warn;crit;min;max
```

For example:

```
rta=0.067ms;200.000;500.000;0;0
```